# Dreamforce 2017 Agenda Builder Bug?

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

Is anyone else on Windows / desktop-Outlook who's registered for Dreamforce and has already used Agenda Builder to enroll in classes getting annoying, incessant prompts to punch some sort of credentials into a prompt so as to access https://success.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/calendar/ical/UC-BigHexNumber/myenrolled.ics as of this morning?

I'm trying to figure out the scope of this nuisance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified the legitimacy of the URL by finding it still buried in the source code of 2016's Agenda Builder after logging into it.

My guess is that Salesforce just "turned off the faucet" for these iCals, and that certain email clients like Outlook are struggling with the fact that I was once subscribed to one of them *(mine)*.

- An HTTP `GET` against last year's iCal URL returns a 403 response w/
  "iCal feed not supported for event" as content.
- An HTTP `GET` against this year's iCal URL returns a 200 response w/
  details about the sessions I'm enrolled in as content.

I suspect that I need to figure out how to unsubscribe from it *(without losing local copies of what I did at Dreamforce last year in my own calendar)*.

Comment: Care to accept this answer so the Community user doesn't keep pinging it?

Comment: Done -- thanks for the note